# v.db.update doesn't write values to a column

Tags: grass-gis, database

I use `v.db.update map=myfile column=label query_column=cat` (areas) to copy column values. This command works well. But when I try do do the same thing for another file which is a product of streams.order command (I added a new column there of course).
`v.db.update map=streams_order column=next2 query_column=next_stream` doesn't write anything there. This map has a layer with two types of geometry, not as the previous myfile, because only areas are there. May be it's the cause.

```
type       count        min        max
point       1264          0       2894
line        1263        370       2894
boundary       0          0          0
centroid       0          0          0
area           0          0          0
face           0          0          0
kernel         0          0          0
all         2527          0       2894
```

UPD: v.info -c gives these types:
TEXT|label
TEXT|next2
TEXT|factor

Comment: What are the date types of each column? Can we see the output of `v.info -c` ?

Comment: Yes, I see.. they are of TEXT type. Should I set up the type while creating the column with addcolumn?

Answer (score 0):

As Micha posted a very good leading question, I realized, that I didn't set up types while creating columns: label int, factor int etc. Now it works well.